# How to write a Flink CEP program where the order of events doesn't matter

Tags: apache-flink, flink-cep

The CEP library makes it simple to write a program to describe that can tell if X is followed by Y.

`val pattern = Pattern.begin("start").where(_.value == "X")
  .next("end).where(_.value == "Y")`

But how would i describe a program where I don't care about the order of X and Y only that one follows the other. e.g X, Y and Y, X are both interesting. However, X,X or Y,Y isn't interesting, so i can't match on a third shared property.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, this feature is not supported out of the box by Flink's CEP library. What you can do is to define these two patterns separately and then union both resulting data streams after the select clause.